# codeigniter and tab contents

Tags: codeigniter, tabs

I have some **tabs** whose contents are fully functional parts of my website.

For instance, in my admin area, I have tabs [add/delete album][add photo][delete photo]. I'm technically dividing the admin area via tabs.

I'm using ajax to load the content into these tabs. tab content area is a div.

The view that is **inside** the tab content area also uses ajax to load stuff. 
These are ajax calls that operates inside the tab content area.

Everything works fine as long as the view inside the tab content area stays same or only part of it changes. But when certain interactions inside tab content area return a whole new view, tab content area would not show them.

I know what happens is that this new view that is returned is not passed into the tab content area div.

In firebug, I can see that ajax success function response shows the new view that is returned.
But I do not know how to pass that new view to the tab content area.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me out in explaining how this could be solved or how contents inside tabs are managed in CI.

```
adminTabsview.php

<ul id="adminTabs"> 
    <li ><?php echo anchor('#album_addDelete', 'Album Add/Delete'); ?></li>     
</ul>   
<div id="adminTabsContent"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#adminTabs a').on({      
    click: function (evt){          
        evt.preventDefault();           
        var page = this.hash.substr(1);          
         adminTabsAjaxCall(page);           
    }   
});
});

function adminTabsAjaxCall ($data){

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php/adminsite_controller/"+ $data + "/",
    dataType: "html",
    data: $data,
    statusCode: {removed}
            },
    success: adminTabContent        

});

function adminTabContent (data){            
    $('#adminTabsContent').html(data);
}
```

---

```
albumsEditDeleteView.php
(this is a view that gets loaded into the tab contentarea div)

<div id="adminTabsContent">
<div id="albumList">
<ul>
<li>
 <a href="#">Asdf</a>
 <a class="add" href="http://localhost/myPHP/photoalbums/index.php/Albums_Controller/add_album/301/Asdf/1/28/0">[ add ]</a>
 <a class="delete" href="http://localhost/myPHP/photoalbums/index.php/Albums_Controller/delete_album/301/Asdf/1/28/0">[ delete ]</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#albumList').on({        
    click: function (evt){          
        evt.preventDefault();   
var $clickedElement = evt.target.tagName;
if ($clickedElement == 'A' ){                
    var urlarray = url.split('/');      
    $chosen.albumid     = urlarray[8];
    $chosen.albumname   = urlarray[9];
    $chosen.lft     = urlarray[10];
    $chosen.rgt     = urlarray[11];
    $chosen.nodeDepth   = urlarray[12]; 
           if ($class == 'add'){                  
     albumajaxcall($chosen);
       }
          if ($class == 'delete'){            
    deleteajaxcall($chosen);
       }            
    }               
}   
});
});


function albumajaxcall($data){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php/Adminsite_Controller/add_album/",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $data,
    statusCode: {removed}
            },
    success: adminTabContent
}); 
}

function adminTabContent(data){         
$('#adminTabsContent').html(data);
}
```

---

```
//heres the view file that has to replace the original view inside 
//tabcontent area
//addnode_view.php
    <?php echo form_open('Albums_Controller/update_albumSet');?>                                
        <input type="text" name="newAlbum" id="newAlbum" value=""/>             
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />        
    <?php echo form_close();?>
    <?php 


//heres the controller function
function add_album(){           
    $levelData ['albumid']      = $this->input->post('albumid');
    <!-- removed-->

    $levelData ['main_content'] = 'addnode_view';   
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $levelData);
}


 //And heres the controller method that loads 
 //the original page (albumsEditDeleteView.php) - this is the original view 
 //that gets loaded into the tab- I get stuck when this view 
 //has to be **totally** replaced through links in the view)

function album_addDelete(){
    $allNodes ['myAlbumList'] = $this->Albums_Model->get_albumList();
    echo $this->load->view('albumsEditDelete_view', $allNodes); 
}
```

thanx in advance.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt if you clarified the question you're asking. Also, please post the relevant code.

Comment: how can i pass the new view to the tab content area?

Comment: Second time reading the question and still a little fuzzy, but thanks for putting code up.  1. have you alerted out "data" from adminTabContent to see if it's filled with something?  2. Are you sure you want the php style "$data" in adminTabsAjaxCall? 3. On a glance it looks like there's an extra } in the ajax code?

Comment: I have posted some more code showing one of the views loaded into the tab. Please note that **success** function is just experimental. I do not know what to do with that function. I just cannot pass the data into the tabcontent div. BTW what do u mean php style? Do you do this a different way in CI. Im very new to CI

Answer (score 0):

basically what you need to do is load whatever new view youll be putting in the tab in the controller function(adminsite_controller/whatever function) that is handling your ajax.

this will basically echo out the view file, which will be viewed as the success variable of your ajax function.

so you have something like this then for the success part of your ajax

```
success:function(msg){adminTabContent(msg);}
```

and in your controller in codeigniter you'll load a view the standard way, but since this will be only loading a piece of the page you may need to create a new view file thats just the div that will be there.  You will do all your data gathering the same way you would if it wasn't ajax.

```
$data['some_data'] = $this->some_model->some_function();
$this->load->view('someview', $data);
```

Comment: thank u for the reply. what u have suggested is what I have already done. like I said in the post, I already have success variable of my ajax function. I can see the whole view using firebug. What I cannot do is get that into the div which displays tab contents(which also means the existing view in the content area will be totally replaced). If u look into my code, u can see that tabs are in a separate view file and contents loaded into the tab is another view file. I guess I shouldnt be trying to pass that data to the tab content div.

Comment: what I'm saying is separate the portion your trying to update with ajax from the tab view file and make it its own view file.  If that still doesn't make sense perhpas posting the controller code that handles the ajax request and the view file its loading, as well as the view file that load the original page will help.

Comment: thank u for trying to help me out. I have posted the code. please take one more glance.

Comment: when you call your adminTabContent function on success you aren't passing it anything.

Comment: I got the answer I think. it seems ive put the wrong datatype in the ajax